# Sitecore publish:end event interaction with user

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a publish:end event handler, and if there is any errors with it, I would like to show it to the user. Is there any way to do this? Can I hook into something to show messages on the publish end screen (or before anywhere)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question intrigued me, because this one of those things that I expect to be possible with Sitecore, but no one really takes the time to find out how.
So I dove into it and I'm pleased to say that it's possible, to a certain end!

In your event handler that is called on `publish:end` you can look up the publish jobs that are currently running.
Once you get the jobs, you can modify its status messages:

```
var publishJobs = Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager
    .GetJobs().Where(x => x.Category.Equals("publish"))
    .ToList();

publishJobs.ForEach(x => x.Status.Messages.Add("This is a message inserted by the publish:end event"));
```

The result will be displayed on the last page of the publication dialog in the Results textbox.

[image]

The thing with the results textarea is that you only see if you click the 'Click here to see additional information' link.

To change that behaviour, you need to modify the dialog XML which is located in `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Publish/Publish.xml`. 
In there you can set the result textarea to be always visible.

There is one drawback though: you can't know which job is your publishing job...

Each job has a handle assigned to it which is basically a Guid and some info about the server and site, but in your event handler you don't have this information (*or at least I can't find it*).

I think in most cases it's no problem to simply add the message to all running publish jobs (after checking if it's already there), but it's something to take into account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess if you go through the route of changing the publish dialog you can modify the code and store the current job handle in session so you can display the message on the correct one

Comment: Yeah, there is always the possibility of taking the code from Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm (or override it) and create an override xml for the Publish dialog that uses your new class as code-behind.

Comment: @RuudvanFalier: many thanks for the thorough investigation! I was also trying to find the job arguments as part of the event, but couldn't find it. Let me try this way, and I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: @RuudvanFalier: FYI, just in case you didn't know already - you can check to see if the job is local by checking the isLocal property of the job in the Foreach loop - i.e. job.Handle.IsLocal - so this way, you don't have to add the message to all the jobs...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can notify the user directly because `publish:end` is executed on another thread which doesn't know about the Sitecore interface. You can send the user an email.

You can also add the [publishing status content editor warning](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Content-Editor-Warning-to-Display-Publishing-Status.aspx) to let editors know whether the publish completed successfully.

I have installed the publishing status on all the sitecore sites I have worked with and users find it very useful.